# PhP session passing and combine variable and string

Tags: php, mysql, session

My login code:

```
<?php
session_start();
$f_usr= $_POST["userid"];
$f_pswd= $_POST["password"];
$_SESSION['user']=$f_usr;
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if(! $con)
{
        die('Connection Failed'.mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("finaltest",$con);
$result=mysql_query("select * from user");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    if($row["username"]==$f_usr && $row["password"]==$f_pswd)
        header('Location: selectdata.php');
    else
        echo"Sorry : $f_usr";
}
?>
```

selectdata.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$s= $_SESSION['user'];
// Make a MySQL Connection
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("finaltest") or die(mysql_error());
$select="temperature".$s;
// Get all the data from the "example" table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $select") 
or die(mysql_error());  

echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr> <th>username</th> <th>password</th> </tr>";
// keeps getting the next row until there are no more to get
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
    // Print out the contents of each row into a table
    echo "<tr><td>"; 
    echo $row['username'];
    echo "</td><td>"; 
    echo $row['password'];
    echo "</td></tr>"; 
} 

echo "</table>";
?>
```

actually the session varibale is not getting parsed i am getting an error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: user in C:\xampp\htdocs\bars\selectdata.php on line 3
```

and i have an other problem i want to select a database named "temperaturexyz" where temperature i want to store in a string and xyz is variable that i am getting via the session i want to combine the both so that i can get a variable which i can use in the query

Comment: That session variable is not being set. You need to figure out why.

Comment: you get every user in the db, and compare password and user-name in a php loop - this is not every efficient (undersatement), instead use a where clause in your select statement

Comment: Does your textbox included in the login code of yours or is it in another file?

Comment: can someone tell how to get "temperaturexyz" in a variable

Comment: `$v='temperaturexyz';`

Comment: temperature is static xyz will come from a session it is dynamic

Comment: Is your table fix to temperaturexyz? What's the purpose of storing them into a variable?

Comment: my table is not fixed actually when a user i registers a table will be created as temperature followed by the username i.e temperatureusername

Comment: $select="temperature".$s; /* You've already declared it. Seems fine with me. */

Comment: but for some reason the session doesnt getpassed

Comment: You wanted to create a table based on the username. - Namely "temperature".$username. Maybe you should rethink about your framework. I think you just need to store them into a table, not creating another table per user.

Comment: i would have done that but the problem is i am creating a website which takes sensor inputs thats the main reson i wanted every user to have a different table so i would not have to make changes in the python scripts that gives value in a particular format any ways thanks

Comment: And maybe the reason of error Notice: Undefined index: user in C:\xampp\htdocs\bars\selectdata.php on line 3 is because $_SESSION['user'] has no data inside, which you need to trace back to your login page. So i'm asking if your textboxes is in the same page with your login page or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Regarding your session:** It appears your session variable `$_SESSION['user']` which you attempt to set in your login code is not correctly setting the variable as expected.
try:

```
<?php
 session_start();
 $f_usr= $_POST["userid"];
$f_pswd= $_POST["password"];
$_SESSION['user']=$f_usr;
echo $_SESSION['user'] //<-------- see if this echo's out the value you are expecting
```

**As for your variable:**
I assume you mean you want a variable name $temperaturexyz but you are creating the variable name dynamically. so

```
$select="temperature".$s;
$$select = /* Insert whatever value you need here*/ //<-- you can then call this variable like this (ie. $temperaturexyz)
```

Comment: try print_r($_SESSION); right after session_start(); and see if there are any values in the $_SESSION. Also try using a different browser an see if you get any different results (Could possible be the browsers cookie settings)

Comment: i have got the session thing working when ever i echo it in the second page i get the value hoever now i get the following error :Table 'finaltest.temperature$select' doesn't exist

Comment: thanks i have got i working finally everythings works fine now and it select the databse too

Comment: I think i need more clarification on what you want to do with your 'temperaturexyz' variable. Do you want a variable with a name $temperaturexyz or do you want a variable with a value of temperaturexyz (i.e. $anyvar = "temperaturexyz";

Comment: Thats great. Glad i could help

Comment: temperature is a constant string  that is stored in a variable and xyz   is a variable that comes from the login page as follows:$select=$_SESSION['user'];
$s="temperature".$select;
// Get all the data from the "example" table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $s")